# Banned myself from my own server, or something with my DNS?

Tags: ssh, ip, blacklist, whitelist

I can't seem to ssh or even browse my site ( medero.org ) even though it's resolving to my server's ip, but other people can.

I was SFTPing some files earlier, but nothing out of the ordinary.

How is it possible that I can't ssh or ping but other people can? I hope I didn't blacklist myself somehow.

The distro is debian, fairly new ( this year ), I don't remember explicitly setting up a blacklist application.

```
me@dunross:~$ ssh user@72.44.90.147
ssh: connect to host 72.44.90.147 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some other issue. A firewall or blacklist rule on their side would result in "connection refused", not a timeout.

Check from another computer on your local network, and if possible from your computer on another network.

Comment: Connections may timeout when firewalled. This is the case, for instance, with iptables if the rule uses the target DROP instead of REJECT.

Comment: Good catch, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Add iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Sounds like the port it blocked on the Debian box.

Answer (score 1):

There are daemons, like fail2ban, that auto-ban IPs that get to many auth errors. They eventually time out the ban, so if you have one of these you could just wait.

Have you tried pinging another IP at the same site. Using whois you can see the IP block of that site and ping another machine. I was able to ping your IP (72.44.90.147) and its neighbor 72.44.90.148 fine. If you can ping other machines at that site that would eliminate a general networking problem.